# for loop is executing indefinitely

Tags: java

Am not able to figure out, why for loop is executing indefinitely even though the condition is given correctly, please help me, its driving me nut.

```
 public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

     //System.out.println(n);
      long[] a = new long[n+1];
      long[] b = new long[n+1];

      for(int k=1;k<=n;k++)
      {
          String[] str = br.readLine().split(" ");
          a[k]=Long.parseLong(str[0]);
          b[k]= Long.parseLong(str[1]);

      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: check the value of n.

Comment: Did you try with some RAW data what is exactly happening in the loop?

Comment: you either have an exception or n is `0`

Comment: It works perfectly. Give a sample of Input and what you are expecting.

Comment: for any value of n, its  reading infinite times.

Answer (score 0):

The java.io.BufferedReader.readline() method read a line of text.

> A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed
>   ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed
>   immediately by a linefeed.

Basically you are not passing any input, br.readLine() is continuously reading from System.in as it is not able to recognize where to terminate the line..

Answer (score 0):

Your program runs perfectly on my machine.

One change I suggest you to do is to use 0 indices not 1.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
long[] a = new long[n];
long[] b = new long[n];

for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    String[] str = br.readLine().split(" ");
    a[k] = Long.parseLong(str[0]);
    b[k] = Long.parseLong(str[1]);
    }
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a) + " " + Arrays.toString(b));

Output:
3
1 2
4 3
6 2
[1, 4, 6] [2, 3, 2]
```

---

Your program expects `n` lines of input after reading `n`, which are 2 longs seperated by a space as Shown above. Make sure the input matches what you want to do. Also make sure the numbers are not seperated by a space in the same line.

```
3 
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

If you do so, according to your logic the arrays would only have the first two numbers, neglecting the rest. As readLine() considers the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

Im not fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but the code compiles and runs and exit with this sample input :
2

5 5

6 6